# Generate all the possible permutations of the first N numbers in Assembly Inline with Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, permutation, inline-assembly

I am new to Assembly Inline in C.
I have to solve the following problem with the inline assembler of Visual Studio:

> Input:
> a DWORD (the number N, N≤ 6)
>
> Output:
> a vector of DWORD (all permutations, see description in the code), a DWORD (the number of permutations)

```c
/*Description: Generate all permutations of the first N natural numbers.
              The permutations generated must be inserted within a single
              array of integers. For example, if N = 3, the array must contain:
              {1,2,3,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,2,1}.*/

#include <stdio.h>


void main()
{
// Variables
int N=4;    // number of integers (try with values ​​<= 6)
int Perm[4326]; // array permutations: size is sufficient for N <= 6
int Num;    // At the end it must contain the number of permutations generated

// asm block
    __asm
    {
        XOR EAX, EAX    //N
        MOV ECX, 1      //Counter
        MOV EDX, 1      //Value of integers <= N

        MOV EAX, N
L1:
        MOV Perm[ECX*4-4], EDX
        INC EDX
        INC ECX
        CMP EDX, EAX
        JLE L1
    }

// Print on video
    {
        int i,j,k;
        printf("Permutations of the first %d natural numbers\n",N);
        for (i=k=0;i<Num;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                printf("%3d",Perm[k++]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to solve this problem but I can't find a solution.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the basic, how to do the maths.

We'll go with very simple maths.

When you have to list all possible combinations of *n* distinct objects, we should first define a path to do so. At first, we could consider the combinations with one, two and three objects (*n* ∈ {1,2,3}), let's go with the objects *A*, *B* and *C* :

1. For only one object, *A*, we have only one possible combination, *A*
2. For two objects, *A* and *B*, we have two possible combinations, [ *A*, *B* ] and [ *B*, *A* ]
3. With three objects, we have then six possible combinations,

   [ *A*, *B*, *C* ] [ *A*, *C*, *B* ]

   [ *B*, *A*, *C* ] [ *B*, *C*, *A* ]

   [ *C*, *A*, *B* ] [ *C*, *B*, *A* ]

What do we see here ?

1. That the number of possible combinations depends directly from the number of objects
2. From one object to two objects, we *double* the number of combinations (1 x 2)
3. From two objects to three objects, we *triple* the number of combinations (2 x 3)

If we take the combinations for three objects, we can clearly see that it is a combinations between object *C* and the combinations of two objects :

[ ***A*, *B***, *C* ] [ ***A***, *C*, ***B*** ]

[ ***B*, *A***, *C* ] [ ***B***, *C*, ***A*** ]

[ *C*, ***A*, *B*** ] [ *C*, ***B*, *A*** ]

So we can see than incrementing *n* gives us *n* x ( *n* - 1 number of possible combinations). Consequently, the number of possible combinations for any *n* is factorial(*n*). If we look closely to the combinations of three objects, we can guess a path for an adequate algorithm to produce all *n* combinations :

[ *A*, *B*, ***C*** ]

[ *B*, *A*, ***C*** ]

[ *A*, ***C***, *B* ]

[ *B*, ***C***, *A* ]

[ ***C***, *A*, *B* ]

[ ***C***, *B*, *A* ]

We can see a pattern here, we have the **two** initial combinations [ *A*, *B* ] and [ *B*, *A* ] to which *C* is added, then we have at the same **two preceding** combinations but this time the second and the third elements are switched ( *C* is in the "middle" ), and , at new the same **two preceding** combinations but this time the first and the second elements are switched ( *C* is at the "start" ). We can then repeat the same pattern with four objects:

1. Simply add *D* to the **six** initial combinations.
2. Then take this **six** resulting combinations and add them at new with a switch of their third and fourth element.
3. Then take this **six** resulting combinations and add them at new with a switch of their second and third element.
4. Then take this **six** resulting combinations and add them at new with a switch of their first and second element.

The pseudo code we can asses from that, with all of our objects in an "objects" collection :

```
Set n to 0
Create empty collection "combinations"
For each object in "objects"
  If n > 0 Then
     Include current object in all combinations of "combinations"
     Set indice to n
     Copy "combinations" to new collection "local combinations"
     While indice > 0
        Create empty collection "new combinations"
        For each combination in "local combinations"
          Create combination witch switch of indice + 1 and indice element of current combination in "new combinations"
        decrement indice 
        Add all combinations of "new combinations" to "combinations"
        If Indice > 0 Then Replace the content of "local combinations" with all combinations of "new combinations" 
  Else
     Create combination with the current object in "combinations"
  Increment n
```

We have here an estime complexity of *O(Factorial(n))* as we iterate *n* times and with each iteration we iterates *n* - 1 times, with *n* as the number of objects.

Before implementing that in assembly, let's go with **C** for clarity :

```
#include <stdio.h>
// There is no standard factorial function in C, lets write a basic one. 
// Considering its limited range, note that a table of known factorials would 
// be far better for perfomance 
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int pNumber) {
   unsigned int lResult = pNumber;
   if (pNumber > 7) {
      // We should not compute that above int32 capacity (max fact 12) and sould not take more than a few kilobytes on the stack, so 7 at max.
      return 0; // If output < pNumber that's mean the function failed 
   }
   while(--pNumber > 0) lResult *= pNumber;
   return lResult;
}
int main(int nbargs, char *args[]) {
  // First, define our number objects, we're going with 4 as an example
  unsigned int number_of_objects = 4;
  // Set n to 0 : Our expected number of objects at the end
  unsigned int n = 0;
  // Create empty collection "combinations" : we need to store "factorial(number_of_objects) * number_of_objects" unsigned int in the end, we take that on the stack
  unsigned int combinations_number = 0;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  unsigned int all_combinations[32000][6];
#else
  unsigned int all_combinations[factorial(number_of_objects)][number_of_objects];
#endif
  // For each object in "objects" : We have to loop on our objects, as it is simply successive integers, we go for a simple loop 
  for (unsigned int object = 1; object <= number_of_objects; object++) {
    // If n > 0 Then : 
    if (n > 0) {
      // Include current object in all combinations of "combinations" : 
      unsigned int indice;
      for (indice = 0; indice < combinations_number; indice++) {
        all_combinations[indice][n] = object;
      }
      // Set indice to n :
      indice = n;
      // Copy "combinations" to new collection "local combinations" :
      unsigned int start = 0;
      unsigned int combinations_number_to_add = combinations_number;
      // While indice > 0
      while(indice > 0) {
        // Create empty collection "new combinations" :
        // For each combination in "local combinations" :
        for (unsigned int local_indice = start; local_indice < start + combinations_number_to_add; local_indice++) {
           // Create combination witch switch of indice + 1 and indice element of current combination in "new combinations" :
           for (unsigned int copy_indice = 0; copy_indice <= n ; copy_indice++) {
             all_combinations[combinations_number][copy_indice] = all_combinations[local_indice][copy_indice];
           }
           all_combinations[combinations_number][indice - 1] = all_combinations[local_indice][indice];
           all_combinations[combinations_number][indice] = all_combinations[local_indice][indice - 1];
           combinations_number++;
        }
        // decrement indice  :
        indice--;
        // Add all combinations of "new combinations" to "combinations" :
        start+=combinations_number_to_add;
        // If Indice > 0 Then Replace the content of "local combinations" with all combinations of "new combinations"  :
      };
    // Else :
    } else {
      // Create combination with the current object in "combinations" : Simply store the "object" in all_combinations 
      all_combinations[combinations_number++][0] = object;
    }
    // Increment n:
    n++;
  }
  // Simple display
  printf("%d \n", combinations_number);
  for (n = 0; n < combinations_number; n++) {
    for (unsigned int nb = 0; nb < number_of_objects; nb++) {
      printf("%d ", all_combinations[n][nb]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

As you can see, we have eliminate here the need of a "local/new" collections with simple array maths, as we simply have integers as "objects".

As i shouldn't do all your homework, i let you how to adapt this C code in MSVC ASM.
At least try.